# Is it good idea to automount partitions on Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, arch-linux, fstab

I have three partitions: one `ext4` for Linux and two `ntfs` partitions (one for Windows and the other for sharing data).

I am really tired of mounting those separately. Is it good idea to edit `fstab` to mount those two NTFS partitions?

Comment: In Ubuntu, nautilus has an option to click on a device/partition (under the left menu) and it mounts automatically as a normal user (in /media/$USER/). I don't know the program that it uses in the background though.. perhaps udisks? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with mounting your own partitions through `ftsab`, that's what it's for. Linux has had good support for reading and writing to NTFS for a long time through `ntfs-3g`. Now I wouldn't recommended automatically mounting your Windows partition unless you have to, since you could accidentally change it's files. If you know what you're doing you should be fine. But for mounting a shared NTFS partition it's perfectly fine. It's a common method of sharing data between the two OS's.

Comment: It should be safe to auto-mount the Windows partition in read-only mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was concerned, because I have lost my data few times, because I occasionally mess things up but I am comfortable with `fstab` and as Scott mentioned, I will mount windows partition in read only mode.